# Rails - How to write Haml with multiple ng attributes (Angular JS) that has Ruby embeded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I want to convert this embedded ruby html

```
<div ng-controller="PollCtrl" ng-init="polls = <%= @plan.polls.to_json %>">
```

and I've tried the following which raises an error

```
%div(ng-controller='PollCtrl', ng-init='polls = @plan.polls.to_json %>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like

```
%div{"ng-controller" => "PollCtrl", "ng-init" => "polls = #{@plan.polls.to_json} "}
```

Which will produce

```
<div ng-controller="PollCtrl" ng-init="polls = <%= @plan.polls.to_json %> ">
```

Tested int [haml2erb.org](https://haml2erb.org/)